# Freeing SCIP_SOL* and SCIP* in SCIP optimization software

Tags: linear-programming, scip

I initialized the scip environment as follows:

```
SCIP* scip = nullptr;
SCIP_CALL( SCIPcreate(&scip) );
```

I created a small problem to learn SCIP and I am storing the solution in

```
SCIP_SOL* sol = nullptr;
sol = SCIPgetBestSol(scip);
```

I am trying to free the memory by `sol` and `scip` but I am running into segmentation faults.

This leads to segfault:

```
SCIP_RETCODE retcode =  SCIPfreeSol(scip,&sol);
assert(retcode == SCIP_OKAY);


retcode = SCIPfree(&scip);
assert(retcode == SCIP_OKAY);
```

If I am not freeing the `sol` before freeing `scip`, it works fine and no seg faults occur but I am sure it is not correct. I have checked some other code which comes with SCIP Optimization Suite and some code examples use `SCIPfreeSol` and some don't, even though they all use `SCIP_SOL *sol` to define the sol variable.

EDIT: The problem actually works. I did not include the actual model code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to free the solution if you created it by `SCIPcreateSol` or similar. When you ask for the best solution via `SCIPgetBestSol(scip)`, this just returns you a pointer to the solution that SCIP created internally. SCIP will also free it, so you don't have to do this yourself. At the same time, since it is not your "own" solution, you should not modify this solution. If you want to do this, you should create your own one or copy the best one via `SCIPcreateSolCopy`.

Therefore, freeing only `scip` is correct in your example.